# How to run tasks on couchdb

Tags: couchdb, couchdb-futon

I need to schedule tasks to run on a couchdb database. These tasks read one db; aggregate data and write them to another database for archival purposes.
I've seen the status page in futon which seems to be a a place to schedule tasks but I'm not able to find any documentation on how to actually accomplish this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Tasks shown in CouchDB's futon are built-in processes such as compaction or replication. You cannot define and run your own tasks here.

For handling your problem, you must run your task as external application that access CouchDB data over the HTTP API, and execute as cronjob, but not within CouchDB.

Comment: +1 It may help to remember CouchDB is a database, like MySQL or SQL Server. It doesn't yet do everything! Sometimes we still have to set up cron or other jobs to query it from the outside.

Comment: Also view map/reduce functions will show up in the tasks view. You can define and run those, but they're far from being arbitrary tasks... they might be useful for data aggregation though.